# Easiest way to create dotted lines for writing answers without exam class

Tags: formatting, exam

I wish to recreate the dotted-line "answer box" seen below. What is the simplest and easiest way to do this? I do not need any of the other functionality of the `exam` class, so I would rather not use that.

[image: Example of dotted-line answer box]

I would like the lines to be `linewidth` in length (so that the length of the lines depend on which level 1)a)i) of the question I'm at), and be 8 mm (0.3 in) apart. I would prefer to specify the number of lines, rather than the space they occupy, but am not averse to simply copy-and-pasting a command once per line required.

It would be a bonus if I could (occasionally) prefix the lines, so when asking for two answers I could have:

1: ...............

2: ...............

Answer (score 2):

For this example I will use a simple list with `\dotfill` for the dotted lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item SubQuestion \label{a}
        \item SubQuestion \label{b}
    \end{enumerate}
    \subitem \ref{a} \dotfill
    \subitem \dotfill
    \subitem \ref{b} \dotfill
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also define your own command `\newcommand\mydotfill{\dotfill\vspace*{...}}` to influence the space between the dotted lines.

Comment: I found that changing the textsize of the `\dotfill` will also have the desired effect, and looks a bit better (in my opinion).  So, I would suggest `\newcommand\mydotfill{\tiny\dotfill}` or something similar.